# Internal Server Error ROS Wiki

Tags: ros, server, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm getting a Internal Server Error when editing/try to access the wiki-page: http://ros.org/wiki/amigo_gazebo . I guess it's the same problem as:http://answers.ros.org/question/12315/getting-an-internal-server-error-while-editing-the-roswiki/ . Can somebody perhaps restore this page? Thanks, Rein

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51311/internal-server-error-ros-wiki/) by [reinzor](https://answers.ros.org/users/3601/reinzor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2013-01-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fixed. You had non-ascii characters inside of a section marked with

```
{{{
#!clearsilver CS/NodeAPI
```

Which caused the page renderer to throw a stack trace and die. Using the preview button before saving a page should help detect this in the future, so that you can correct it before it becomes permanent.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3